# Eliminate need for grep use only awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to generate a list of PID's to pass to strace I only want the PID's php-fpm.  I can get the correct output by using grep with awk but am looking for an awk only answer.  Here is what I have done.

This gives the desired output:

```
$ ps ajxf |grep '[p]hp-fpm: pool' |awk '{print $2}'
21547
21548
21549
21938
31131
31132
31133
31189
36283
10549
12179
12893
12964
12989
13565
14420
14421
15848
17737
```

This one did not:

```
$ ps ajxf |awk '/php-fpm: pool/{if (NR!=1) {print $2}}'
22903  <--- This is the PID of the awk
21547
21548
21549
21938
31131
31132
31133
31189
36283
10549
12179
20328
20392
20393
20618
22006
22793
22794
22804
```

Comment: You can use square brackets in the AWK version in the same way that you used them in the `grep` version. Also, you don't need to use `if`: `awk '/php-fpm: pool/ && NR != 1 {print $2}'`, but `pidof` is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might find [pidof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof) much easier to use.

```
pidof php
24293 19810 19467
```

---

You can use `~` to match a field and `^` to anchor the match to the beginning of the field.

```
awk '$6 ~ /^something/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: That also returns the php-fpm master process which I do not want

Comment: your second answer did the trick.  Both of these work what is it that the carrot does exactly `ps ajxf |awk '$12 ~ /^pool/{print $2,$13}'` `ps ajxf |awk '$12 ~ /pool/{print $2,$13}'`